# devtools::check() Error: Dependency package(s) 'flextable' not available

Tags: r, devtools, flextable

I have small package of functions called `bfuncs`. When I run devtools::check() in RStudio I get the following error:

```
==> devtools::check()

Updating bfuncs documentation
Loading bfuncs
Warning in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = "*")  :
  Dependency package 'flextable' not available.
Error: Dependency package(s) 'flextable' not available.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Flextable is listed under `Imports:` in my package `DESCRIPTION` file.

Flextable is installed on my machine and I'm using it interactively without any problems. I've tried reinstalling in the manner shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199737/cant-install-flextable).

These posts seem to sort of relate to my problem, but I wasn't able to get a solution from them: 
[Package imports error on devtools::check()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335991/package-imports-error-on-devtoolscheck)
[Dependency package "package_name" not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428055/dependency-package-package-name-not-available)
[How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

In response to @MrFlick, `installed.packages()["flextable","Version”]` returns `”0.4.6”`. Yes, `devtools` and `flexible` are installed on the same machine and that is the machine I’m running `devtools::check()` on. The version of `devtools` I’m using is `”2.0.1”`.

Any help getting rid of this error is appreciated.

Comment: So what does `installed.packages()["flextable","Version"]`return? Are you are calling `devtools::check` on the same machine? What version of `devtools` are you using?

Comment: @brad-cannell I think I found your repo and package `flextable` is not listed in `Imports:`

Comment: Hi @DavidGohel. Thanks for taking a look. You're right it's not on Github, because adding flextable to Imports in my description file causes the error above to be thrown. I was trying to resolve the error before committing to Github. Does that make sense?

Comment: @BradCannell Maybe you have a local issue... I added flextable to `imports:`, added `#' @import flextable` somewhere in your scripts and voila, your package checks ok: `0 errors ✔ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔`. If it is what you did, I can not reproduce :/

Comment: @DavidGohel Thanks! I appreciate you trying so hard to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but reinstalling [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) seems to have fixed the issue.